# Storyboard and launch image showing both

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to create a splashscreen for my iOS app targeting iOS 7.0+ devices. I am new to this storyboard thing. But basically I need my logo to have a certain size depending whether it is on phones or on pads.

1. I created a storyboard and added a view and an entry point.
2. In the `.plist` file I specified the storyboard as launch image.
3. The project also has launch images as I want to be backward compatible with devices prior to 8.0.

When I run the app, I can see the storyboard kicking in, but a few instants later one of the launch images appears. It is like the storyboard kicks in, but also the splashscreen images do. But the splashscreen images should kick in only in devices prior to 8.0.

What am I doing wrong?